# how to source _env file in windows

Tags: python, flask, twilio, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup twilio using python `virtualenv`. I have an `_env` file which includes some api_keys which need to be sourced to the application. How can I run `source _env` command on windows or is there some alternative?

Following is my current `_env' format:

```
$Env:TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=""
$Env:TWILIO_API_KEY=""
$Env:TWILIO_API_SECRET=""
$Env:TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID=""
$Env:TWILIO_CONFIGURATION_SID ""
```

It throws an `keyError`
[image]

Comment: What is the format of your `_env` file? Please update your question with an example of what the file looks like (with sensitive data removed, of course). Is it a shell script or `NAME=value` pairs?

Comment: please check now, edited!

Comment: What throws a KeyError? Add the full traceback

Comment: added an image!

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri please don't add images, copy and paste the actual traceback and format it as code in your question.

Comment: I have no idea what that `$Env:` syntax is used for, but it's not windows or unix based, so I think Twilio includes its own parser

Answer (score 1):

If your `_env` file was set up as key/value pairs like this

```
API_KEY=12345abcde
OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL=https://example.com/callback
```

Then you could easily parse this using [python-dotenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dotenv)

Additionally, if you didn't want to use the library, you could pretty easily write your own parsing loop that could work with either your file format or the dotenv format.